# What is the proper name for this number system?

Tags: terminology, complex-numbers

The FractInt documentation makes mention of two number systems which extend the complex numbers: the "quaternions" and the "hypercomplex numbers".

However, Wikipedia claims that "hypercomplex number" is not a number system but a *type* of number system. So, does anybody know specifically which system FractInt is referring to?

http://www.nahee.com/spanky/www/fractint/append_a_misc.html#hcpx_math_anchor

Relevant excerpt:

- $\{1, i, j, k\}$ are the key elements of the set.
- This is a field, but for the lack of inverses for all elements. (In particular, addition and multiplication are both associative and commutative.)
- $i^2 = j^2 = -k^2 = -1$.
- $ij = ji = k$.
- $jk = kj = -i$.
- $ki = ik = -j$.

PS. POV-Ray also refers to these same two number systems:

http://www.povray.org/documentation/view/3.6.1/280/

Comment: @TheChaz Look at that set: only 4 elements, not 8...

Comment: Oh, sorry I misread.

Comment: Tessarines, plain and simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To distinguish them from what others (including myself) might call the 'standard hypercomplex numbers,' I would call these the Davenport hypercomplex numbers.

More information about them can be found at [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypercomplexNumber.html) or at [Davenport's Page](http://home.comcast.net/~cmdaven/hyprcplx.htm).

Comment: Davenport's page looks damned interesting, and quite readable...

Answer (score 4):

It appears to be the algebra of [bicomplex numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicomplex_number). Note that wikipedia's $j$ is your $k$ and vice versa.

Comment: There's also a sign change somewhere along the line; the OP has $ij = k$ but Wikipedia has $ik = -j$.

Comment: You're right, I missed that. They're definitely isomorphic (by some results on Davenport's page); finding an isomorphism would be a fun exercise. :)

Answer (score 0):

These numbers are called the "Circular" hypercomplex numbers in Olariu, S. (2000), “Commutative Complex Numbers in Four Dimensions”, Institute of Physics  and Nuclear  Engineering, Bucharest, Romania